# Passar ViewBag para _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso passar uma lista para meu layout onde é utilizado em todas as minhas paginas, gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: se vc declarar um viewbag em todos os controler vc pode usar no layout

Comment: O que você quer exibir com o ViewBag?

Comment: Uma lista para preencher um dropdow

Comment: Teria como dizer mais ou menos como seria essa lista?

Comment: seria um List<SelectListItem> preenchida com um objeto

Comment: Essa lista é originada de onde?? Um Entity Framework?

Comment: Eu preencho ela com os dados que pego manualmente do banco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o código é usado em todas as páginas, possivelmente é um layout ou um menu dinâmico. **Não use `Session` pra isso**.

Vou passar uma lista de passos para criar um menu dinâmico.

## 1. Crie um *Controller* comum

Crie um arquivo chamado `Controller.cs` no diretório `Controllers` do seu projeto com o seguinte:

```
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{

}
```

Isto garante que todos os *Controllers* da sua aplicação são derivados deste.

## 2. Crie *Actions* com o *Attribute* [`[ChildActionOnly]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

O *Attribute* garante que a *Action* só possa ser chamada por outra, e nunca diretamente.

Exemplo:

```
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    ...
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        var menu = contexto.EntidadeDoMenu.ToList();

        return PartialView(menu);
    }
    ...
}
```

## 3. Crie uma *View* para cada *Action* criada no *Controller* comum no diretório `Views\Shared`

Um exemplo (arquivo `Views\Shared\Menu.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.ItemDeMenu>

<ul>
    @foreach (var itemDeMenu in Model) { 
       <li>@Html.ActionLink(itemDeMenu.Nome, "Detalhes", "UmControllerQualquer", new { id = itemDeMenu.Id }, null)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

## 4. Faça `_Layout.cshtml` chamar a *Action*

Este passo é opcional. Você pode fazer outro componente chamar a *Action*.

```
@Html.Action("Menu")
```

Comment: A View do Menu (arquivo Views\Shared\Menu.cshtml) precisa ser uma partial view?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar implementar aqui, qualquer coisa eu retorno.

Comment: Respondendo a mim mesmo, vi no código que você retorna uma PartialView, explicitamente.

Comment: @Intruso Exatamente. A ideia é encerrar o escopo da *Action* pra que ela não possa ser chamada de maneiras estranhas.

Comment: Fiz desta forma e funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja mais ou menos assim o que você queira:

```
List<SelectListItem> listItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
List<SeuModel> listModel = repositorio.BuscarDados();

foreach(var item in listModel)
{
   listItem.Add({
      Text: item.Descricao,
      Value: item.Id
   });
}

ViewBag.seuDropDownList = listItem;
```

Me desculpe caso haja erros no código, não estou com as dlls e componentes pra testar.

Comment: Eu ja estou conseguindo preencher a Viewbag com essa lista, estou com problema na hora de usar essa ViewBag no _Layout, n sei em qual controller devo passar essa informação.

Answer (score 0):

O @Cigano provavelmente deve saber uma solução melhor, mas a única coisa que pensei foi de adicionar na própria `Session`, exemplo:

```
var selectList = new SelectList (suaLista, "ID", "Texto");
Session.Add("meudropdown", selectList);
```

E na `_Layout`

```
@Html.DropDownList("meudrop", Session["meudropdown"] as SelectList)
```